# Stripe Payments in PHP With Namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces, stripe-payments

I built a PHP application that uses namespaces and PSR-0 autoloading. In trying to implement the [Stripe](http://www.stripe.com) library, I've found that it can't seem to load the classes because they aren't namespaced. Is there a way to not autoload if I have manually included the files?

```
// Get Stripe Library
require_once(App\App::$APP_PATH . "/Extensions/Stripe.php");

// Set Key
Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);
```

Setting the key in the example fails with a fatal error because it thinks a `Stripe` class exists in my namespace of the current file.

I found that if I add a `use Stripe;` line below my namespace declaration, it will work, but then fails on the next class in the Stripe library.

Am I really going to have to add a `Use Stripe, Stripe_Customer, Stripe_xyz...;` line to let it load the files correctly (which there are over 25 files) or is there a better way?

[**EDIT**]

Until I hear whether there is a better way, I've done this:

```
// Import Non-Namespaced Stripe Library
use Stripe, Stripe_Account, Stripe_ApiConnectionError, Stripe_ApiError, Stripe_ApiRequestor, Stripe_ApiResource, Stripe_AuthenticationError;
use Stripe_Card, Stripe_CardError, Stripe_Charge, Stripe_Coupon, Stripe_Customer, Stripe_Error, Stripe_Event, Stripe_InvalidRequestError;
use Stripe_Invoice, Stripe_InvoiceItem, Stripe_List, Stripe_Object, Stripe_Plan, Stripe_Recipient, Stripe_SingletonApiResource;
use Stripe_Stripe, Stripe_Token, Stripe_Transfer, Stripe_Util;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using composer is the easiest way (I promise!)

Just [install composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx) and then [install stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/libraries#php-library). Once you have those installed just browse to your project's folder and run `composer install`. This will install the needed dependencies and will put composer in a folder called vendor.

Then you simple require the autoload.php file which will load up stripe, without bothering to use a namespace. Here's a full example block that I [grabbed from here](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/php).

```
<?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

$stripe = array(
  "secret_key"      => "sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2",
  "publishable_key" => "pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh"
);

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\` to specify that the class name you're specifying is a fully qualified namespace (FQNS), for example:

```
<?php
use \Stripe, \Stripe_Account;

$stripe = new Stripe();
$stripe_account = new Stripe_Account();
```

or without `use` statements:

```
<?php
$stripe = new \Stripe();
$stripe_account = new \Stripe_Account();
```

Comment: How is that any better than what I ended up doing? You are suggesting I basically do the same thing I did only with a namespacing prefix. This actually takes more work to do.

Comment: I was only suggesting a solution to your problem: "Am I really going to have to add a `Use Stripe, Stripe_Customer, Stripe_xyz...;` line"